# Importing excel with merged cells in R

Tags: r, excel, import

I have a data set whose first column is merged with 4 columns in excel. When I import the same in R only this column gets imported while the others don't. Could you please suggest me how to import the data correctly.

Comment: Please show us the structure of your Excel worksheet if possible.

Comment: ...and how are you reading it into R?

Comment: if you are reading a CSV file make sure you have the trailing `,,,` on the row you are merging.

Comment: the data is in a XLS format, the first few rows are blanks and then the data starts.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

`data = read.csv("FILE_NAME.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep = "\t")`

it should work.
And to delete the first rows, then it is easier this way:

`data[,firstROWnumberTOdelete:secondROWnumberTOdelete] <- NULL`